# Declaring an array of vars with an array of sets

Tags: arrays, set, minizinc

I'm pretty new to minizinc, and this might be a simple question, but I can't find the answer anywhere so I'm resorting to asking here.

I have this array:

```
set of int: N=1..n;
array[N] of set of int: x_d = [ { j | j in i+1..min(2*i,n-1) } | i in N];
```

`n` is subject to change, it's inputted externally, so I don't have access to that value in writing this code. What I want is this array of variables:

```
array[N] of var int: x;
```

to be restricted to the sets above. Meaning, `x[i]` should be restricted to its corresponding set `x_d[i]`, where `i` belongs to `[1, 2, ..., n]`.

Comment: what language are you programming in?

Comment: I'm modelling a constraint satisfaction problem with minizinc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would `constraint forall(i in N)(x[i] in x_d[i]);` suit your needs?